# How to access the Object property within the method inside the Object in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React hooks and been playing with the useState function lately.. In vanilla javascript this code works:

```
const state = {
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  greeting: function(){
     return sayHello(this.firstname,this.lastname)
  }
}

const sayHello = (fname,lname)=>{
  return `Hello i'm ${fname} ${lname}, nice to meet you!`;
}

console.log(state.greeting()); //outputs "Hello i'm John Doe, nice to meet you!"
```

But with React hooks:

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  greeting: function(){
    return sayHello(this.firstName,this.lastName)
  }
})

const sayHello = (fname,lname) => console.log(`Hello i'm ${fname} ${lname}, nice to meet you!`);

const { firstName, lastName, greeting } = state;
return (
    <div>
        <button className="btn" onClick={greeting()}>Greet</button>
    </div>
)
```

I get an error saying: "Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined", and i also get [object object] if i just use the "firstName" and "lastName" within the method without the "this" keyword. How can i access the variables?

Comment: You don't use `greeting` in the code above.

Comment: @Twirlman, can you show how you are calling `greeting` in 2nd snippet, it should work.

Comment: @estus let's say for example it's attached to an onClick button.

Comment: @Twirlman you will get all the answers here: [**How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback), solution to your problem is: `onClick={greeting.bind(state)}` now when `greeting` method will get called, `this` will point to state value and it will work perfectly. Without proper binding of context `this` will be undefined inside event handler function.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're not calling the `greeting` method, you should call it in order to get your code working.

Second, you should keep your state as lean as possible, so rethink twice before assigning a method to your state, there's a better place to place it in.

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('John');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('Doe');

const greeting = () => {
  console.log(`Hello i'm ${firstName} ${lastName}, nice to meet you!`);
}
```

Then somewhere in your code call `greeting()`.

As you can see, we're assigning the `firstName` and `lastName` variables with their initial values and their respective setters thanks to react hooks, so you can call them directly in your code.

```
console.log(`Hi, my name is ${firstName}`) // Hi, my name is John
```

And if you run `setFirstName('David')` and after that, you run again:

```
console.log(`Hi, my name is ${firstName}` // Hi, my name is David
```

You will get the updated version of `firstName`, that's better isn't?

Comment: Ok sorry i didn't include the whole code. i'm calling it on a button. But let's say i'm going to pass it as a prop using context api. I'm using useContext so i should include the greeting function inside the state right? provided i have enclosed my return statement inside a provider... I can destructure it into  const { firstName, lastName , greeting } = useContext(mycontext);

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility for the error to occur is that `greeting` is used with wrong context, e.g. as a callback. This can be fixed by hard-coding it to use correct object:

```
  ...
  greeting: () => sayHello(state.firstname, state.lastname)
  ...
```

React and React hooks encourage the use of FP instead of OOP. If there are no reasons to keep `greeting` method as a part of the state, it can be:

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe"
});

const { firstName, lastName } = state;
const greeting = () => sayHello(firstName, lastName);
```

`useCallback` is not necessary but it may help in some cases:

```
const greeting = useCallback(() => sayHello(firstName, lastName), [firstName, lastName]);
```

Comment: But what if you want to pass greeting method as context using the "useContext" to other nested components? so it should be in the state right?

Comment: @Twirlman Then you should consider it a callback and keep in mind that callbacks lose `this`, unless they are bound. As for useState, the simplest way is to refer to `state` object directly instead of `this`.